# Making Pandas work with Pendulum

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, pendulum

I've recently stumbled upon a new awesome [`pendulum` library](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) for easier work with datetimes.

In `pandas`, there is this handy [`to_datetime()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) allowing to convert series and other objects to datetimes:

```
raw_data['Mycol'] = pd.to_datetime(raw_data['Mycol'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

What would be the canonical way to create a custom `to_<something>` method -
 in this case `to_pendulum()` method which would be able to convert Series of date strings directly to [`Pendulum` objects](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#instantiation)?

This may lead to `Series` having various interesting capabilities like, for instance, converting a series of date strings to a series of ["offsets from now" - human datetime diffs](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#difference-for-humans).

Comment: Hmm, what do you have in mind? You can subclass `Series` objects, wherein you can add a `to_pendulum` method that does what you want.

Comment: [Here's](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures) the official guide on subclassing series.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I was initially thinking about just calling an `apply()` method, but then I have a very limited knowledge of pandas and was not sure about the most appropriate way to create a custom conversion method like this.  Will read the guide, thanks!

Comment: Ah, alright. It seems like I misunderstood. So, you have a column of datetimes and you'd like to apply this pendulum diff_for_humans function? (sorry, I'm unfamiliar with this library). If it's as simple as that, you could just define a function and pass it to `pd.Series.apply`, subclassing a Series would just be overkill.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no problem, I was not clear enough. I was thinking to initially convert a column (series) of datetime strings to a column of Pendulum objects so that later on be able to make datetime operations easier - human datetime ldifferences, timezone conversions and other convenient things that pendulum offers.

Comment: Actually, I retract my first answer. I don't think converting a series to a pendulum object is a great idea. 1) Pandas does not natively support pendulum 2) You will not see any performance benefits 3) Pandas attempts to coerce anything that it can to a known format, so it keeps trying to caste pendulum objects to timestamp. This is going to keep biting you multiple times.

Comment: This is a consequence of the fact that `isinstance(pendulum.now(), datetime.datetime) >>> True`, so pandas special cases this sort of object, coercing it where possible to `Timestamp`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ah, did not know these things about pandas. Would really appreciate if you could summarize it in an answer. Thanks, learned something new today!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What would be the canonical way to create a custom `to_<something>`
>   method - in this case `to_pendulum()` method which would be able to
>   convert Series of date strings directly to `Pendulum` objects?

After looking through the API a bit, I must say I'm impressed with what they've done. Unfortunately, I don't think `Pendulum` and `pandas` can work together (at least, with the current latest version - `v0.21`).

The most important reason is that `pandas` does not natively support `Pendulum` as a datatype. All the natively supported datatypes (`np.int`, `np.float` and `np.datetime64`) all support vectorisation in some form. You are not going to get a shred of performance improvement using a dataframe over, say, a vanilla loop and list. If anything, calling `apply` on a `Series`  with `Pendulum` objects is going to be *slower* (because of all the API overheads).

Another reason is that `Pendulum` is a subclass of `datetime` -

```
from datetime import datetime

isinstance(pendulum.now(), datetime)
True
```

This is important, because, as mentioned above, `datetime` is a supported datatype, so pandas will *attempt* to coerce `datetime` to pandas' native datetime format - `Timestamp`. Here's an example.

```
print(s)

0     2017-11-09 18:43:45
1     2017-11-09 20:15:27
2     2017-11-09 22:29:00
3     2017-11-09 23:42:34
4     2017-11-10 00:09:40
5     2017-11-10 00:23:14
6     2017-11-10 03:32:17
7     2017-11-10 10:59:24
8     2017-11-10 11:12:59
9     2017-11-10 13:49:09

s = s.apply(pendulum.parse)
s

0    2017-11-09 18:43:45+00:00
1    2017-11-09 20:15:27+00:00
2    2017-11-09 22:29:00+00:00
3    2017-11-09 23:42:34+00:00
4    2017-11-10 00:09:40+00:00
5    2017-11-10 00:23:14+00:00
6    2017-11-10 03:32:17+00:00
7    2017-11-10 10:59:24+00:00
8    2017-11-10 11:12:59+00:00
9    2017-11-10 13:49:09+00:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, <TimezoneInfo [UTC, GMT, +00:00:00, STD]>]

s[0]
Timestamp('2017-11-09 18:43:45+0000', tz='<TimezoneInfo [UTC, GMT, +00:00:00, STD]>')

type(s[0])
pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp
```

So, with some difficulty (involving `dtype=object`), you could load `Pendulum` objects into dataframes. Here's how you'd do that -

```
v = np.vectorize(pendulum.parse)
s = pd.Series(v(s), dtype=object)

s

0     2017-11-09T18:43:45+00:00
1     2017-11-09T20:15:27+00:00
2     2017-11-09T22:29:00+00:00
3     2017-11-09T23:42:34+00:00
4     2017-11-10T00:09:40+00:00
5     2017-11-10T00:23:14+00:00
6     2017-11-10T03:32:17+00:00
7     2017-11-10T10:59:24+00:00
8     2017-11-10T11:12:59+00:00
9     2017-11-10T13:49:09+00:00

s[0]
<Pendulum [2017-11-09T18:43:45+00:00]>
```

However, this is essentially useless, because calling *any* `pendulum` method (via `apply`) will now not only be super slow, but will also end up in the result being coerced to `Timestamp` again, an exercise in futility.

Comment: For future readers...Github issue on making pandas work with pendulum: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15986