# Airflow error with pandas: AttributeError: 'Pendulum' object has no attribute 'nanosecond'

Tags: python, pandas, airflow, pendulum

I have a pandas.DataFrame `df` with `df.index` which yeilds something like this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-10-06 00:55:11.357899904',
               '2014-10-06 00:56:39.046799898',
               '2014-10-06 00:56:39.057499886',
               '2014-10-06 00:56:40.684299946',
               '2014-10-06 00:56:41.115299940',
               '2014-10-06 01:03:52.764300108',
               '2014-10-06 01:21:18.448499918',
               '2014-10-06 01:21:18.457200050',
               '2014-10-06 01:21:18.584199905',
               '2014-10-06 01:21:18.594700098',
               ...
               '2014-11-05 00:25:47.996000051',
               '2014-11-05 00:56:45.081799984',
               '2014-11-05 00:56:45.096899986',
               '2014-11-05 05:50:57.639699936',
               '2014-11-05 06:08:56.365000010',
               '2014-11-05 06:11:20.519099950',
               '2014-11-05 06:15:03.470400095',
               '2014-11-05 06:15:03.981600046',
               '2014-11-05 06:25:31.514300108',
               '2014-11-05 06:25:59.310400009'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', length=1000, freq=None)
```

I am running a DAG on airflow, which stops at the following line `df.loc[start_date:end_date]`, saying that:

```
AttributeError: 'Pendulum' object has no attribute 'nanosecond'
```

I cannot reproduce the error without running the code in Airflow. The same code runs just fine without Airflow.

The `start_date` is the [Airflow macro](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros) `execution_date` and `end_date` is the `next_execution_date`.

I guess the issues is to do with the date-time `dtype` of the `df` not being compatable with the ones from the `start_date` & `end_date`, but I have no idea how to address it.

I tried removing time zones, changing the `dtype` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching, I found the source of the problem and a solution.

**the problem**

The issue is caused by the two macros passed down from Airflow:

- `start_date`, which is the `execution_date` macro
- `end_date`, which is the `next_execution_date` macro

The types of them are `pendulum.datetime`, and not `datetime.datetime`, as the Airflow documentation says. This causes the clash with `pandas.DataFrame`.

`pandas` and `pendulum` currently don't work well together and the problem is well described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849342/making-pandas-work-with-pendulum) StackOverflow asnwer.

**the solution**

The solution seesm to convery the `start_date` and `end_date` from `pendulum.datetime` to `datetime.datetime`.

For this I created this simple function, which converts from to string beofore converting to `datetime.datetime`. I am sure they are better ways to do it, but this was quite simple and safe, hence why I used it.

Here is the function itself:

```
def pendulum_to_datetime(pendulum_date):
    """
    Convert pendulum to datetime format.

    The conversion is done from pendulum -> string -> dateime.

    Args:
        pendulum_date (pendulum): The date you wish to convert.

    Returns:
        (datetime) The converted date.
    """
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
    string_date = pendulum_date.strftime(fmt)
    return datetime.strptime(string_date, fmt)
```